# Массив строк после заполнения выводит null

Tags: java, массивы, null

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        n=sc.nextInt();
        String[] f=new String[n+2];
        f[0]='.'+ "#".repeat(n+1);// debug пишет, что f[0] после выполнения этой строке остается пустым
        for (int i = 1; i <n+1; i++) {
            String s=sc.next();
            f[i]='#'+s+'#';
        }
        flood(1,1,f);
        flood(n,n,f);
        //внутренняя функция, не имеющая значение в изменении f
        System.out.println(25*r);
    }
```

Данный код при запуске дебага выводит, что `f` - множество пустых строк, несмотря на вводимые строки.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема НЕ воспроизводится, массив заполняется как и положено (ссылка не создается, поэтому использовал скриншот).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема может быть с незаполненным ***последним элементом*** массива `f`, что в принципе ожидаемо, так как по индексу `n - 1` ничего не было записано.

Вероятно, в первую и последнюю ячейку `f` должна быть записана одинаковая строка, что достигается кодом:

```java
f[0] = f[f.length - 1] = '.' + "#".repeat(n + 1);
```